# Swift - "Alamofire.upload" -> "AF.upload" issue with the Upload function

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have upgraded the pod Alamofire 5.0 from an older version,

From the Migrating Guide
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%205.0%20Migration%20Guide.md

**"MultipartFormData’s API has changed and the top level upload methods to create and upload MultipartFormData have been updated to match other request APIs, so it’s not longer necessary to deal with the Result of the multipart encoding."**

I have the below function written, i am unable to re-write this in the new version, Can anyone help me on this regard?

note:
**I think i need to change the "Alamofire.upload" -> "AF.upload", however its not along is enough to fix the problem,**

```
func uploadPhoto(token:String, userID: String, data: Data, dataUrl: URL) -> Observable<AnyObject?> {
        return Observable<AnyObject?>.create({ (observer) -> Disposable in
            print(userID);
            print(data);
            
            do {
                let urlRequest = try URLRequest(url: ResourcePath.Upload.path + "/\(userID)" , method: .post)
                Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartData) in
                    multipartData.append(data, withName: "Filedata", fileName: dataUrl.absoluteURL.lastPathComponent, mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                    //append(dataUrl, withName:  "Filedata",  fileName: dataUrl.absoluteString, mimeType: "image/png")
                    
                }, with: urlRequest, encodingCompletion: { (result) in
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let value, let t1, let t2) :
                        print(value)
                        value.responseData(completionHandler: { (dataResponse) in
                            switch (dataResponse.result) {
                            case .success(let value) :
                                print(value)
                                do {
                                    
                                   
                                    let jsonData = JSON(dictData)
                                    print("Upload photo response: \(jsonData)")
                                    observer.onNext(jsonData as AnyObject?)
                                    observer.onCompleted()
                                }
                                catch {
                                    print(error)
                                    observer.onError(error)
                                    return
                                }
                                break
                            case .failure(let error) :
                                print(error)
                                observer.onError(error)
                                break
                            }
                        })
                        
                        break
                    case .failure(let error) :
                        print(error)
                        observer.onError(error)
                        break
                    default:
                        break
                    }
                })
            } catch {
                print(error)
                observer.onError(error)
            }
            return Disposables.create {
                print("disposed")
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: You want somebody to rewrite your code without trying it for yourself?  I don't think that's a good idea.

Comment: Have you tried the AF.upload instead of Alamofire.upload ?

Comment: I can't figure out how to make the changes

Comment: Af.upload dont work

Comment: i get a error "Expression type 'UploadRequest' is ambiguous without more context"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alamofire 5 has removed the need for the `encodingCompletion` closure when using multipart form encoding. Instead, you can use the normal response handling as seen in other use cases. For example:

```swift
AF.upload(multipartFormData: { data in
    // Build your multipart form.
}).responseDecodable(of: SomeType.self) { response in
    // Handle response.
}
```